# How do I get the current step in jQuery steps wizard?

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

I'm looking for a way to get the current step in my [jQuery Steps wizard](http://www.jquery-steps.com/). I would like to perform an action if the current step is step 1.

Comment: Not sure how this is unclear, the people who have provided answers also seem to find it quite clear.

Answer (score 7):

This will return the current step index as an integer.

```
$("#wizard").steps("getCurrentIndex");
```

This step index is zero-based.

So, to perform an action on the first step (what I assume you mean by "step 1"), you would do:

```
if ( $("#wizard").steps("getCurrentIndex") == 0 ) {
    perform_action();
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Methods

Answer (score 2):

There are [`onStepChanging` and `onStepChanged`](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Settings#events) events which have `currentIndex` parameter. You can place your action inside the function for handling any of these events.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in the example code found in the download at:

https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps

Here's the snippet I found useful:

```
            // Example 1: Basic wizard with validation
            $( "#example-1" ).wizard({
                submit: ".submit",
                beforeForward: function( event, state ) {

                    if ( state.stepIndex === 1 ) {
                        $("#name").text($("[name=name]").val());

                    } else if ( state.stepIndex === 2 ) {
                        $("#gender").text($("[name=gender]").val());
                    }
                    return $( this ).wizard( "form" ).valid();
                }
            }).wizard( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert( "Form submitted!" );

            }).validate( validate );
```

Comment: is not detecting the event, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to disabled step 1 and 2 if the current step is 3, add this code to jquery.steps.js

```
$.fn.steps.done = function () {
  var wizard = this,
  options = getOptions(this),
  state = getState(this);

  if(state.currentIndex == 2){
      for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var stepAnchor = getStepAnchor(wizard, i);
        stepAnchor.parent().removeClass("done")._enableAria(false);
      }
  }
};
```

and add this to your html

```
$("#wizard").steps('done');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.selected').prop('rel')
```

For SmartWizard 3.3.1, the selected step always has a `class='selected'`. Thus using that class, you can manipulate based on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#wizard").smartWizard("currentStep");
```

for old version.